# Transform JSON to tabular format with JSON input

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api

I am looking to transform an API's response to a tabular structure where all the key will become the column name and the corresponding values will be respective values. The issue is that in the output JSON the attribute "details" has multiple and random keys in it. I am trying to achieve the output where the columns will be respective attributes and also want to create columns using the keys from the "details" attribute

I tried this to convert but due to my limited knowledge on python I have failed so far.

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "Robert",
    "last_name": "Bradford",
    "Children": [
      "Jack",
      "Lindsey"
    ],
    "details": {
      "age": "42",
      "city": "New York",
      "state": "NY"
    }
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Simon",
    "last_name": "Warters",
    "Children": [
      "Megan"
    ],
    "details": {
      "age": "35",
      "city": "Buffalo",
      "pin": "14220",
      "secured": "yes",
      "citizen": "yes"
    }
  }
]
```

|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      first_name     |     last_name    |      children       |     age          |      city           |     state        |      pin            |     secured      |      citizen        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          Robert     |     Bradford     |  Jack,Lindsey       |         42       |          New York   |         NY       |                     |                  |                     |
|          Simon      |         Warters  |          Megan      |         35       |          Buffalo    |                  |          14220      |         yes      |          yes        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, Hope this will be helpful.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = [
  {
    "first_name": "Robert",
    "last_name": "Bradford",
    "Children": [
      "Jack",
      "Lindsey"
    ],
    "details": {
      "age": "42",
      "city": "New York",
      "state": "NY"
    }
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Simon",
    "last_name": "Warters",
    "Children": [
      "Megan"
    ],
    "details": {
      "age": "35",
      "city": "Buffalo",
      "pin": "14220",
      "secured": "yes",
      "citizen": "yes"
    }
  }
]
train = json_normalize(data)

print(train)
```

Read more about pandas, [from here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

Comment: Hi @Shishir.
I have 75+ columns, with pandas all the columns are not displayed. I used the option of 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)

but with this the formatting is changing and later its becoming hard to define the delimiter between the values to align them with the columns.
Only delimiter which is common is a space but with space data is getting affected as well.